# How to assign series of values to an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `foreach` loop to assign values to an array.

```
$route_selection;
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $from_state = $route->fromState->name;
        $to_state = $route->toState->name;
        $from_country = $route->fromCountry->name;
        $to_country = $route->tocountry->name; 
        $route_selection[] = [$route->hash_id => 'From: '.$from_state.' ('.$from_country.') To: '.$to_state.' ('.$to_country.')'];
    }
```

Sure enough, it will have a result to something like this:
[image]

But I want the result to be something like this:
[image]

How can I possibly do that in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your array assigning line to:

```
$route_selection[$route->hash_id] = 'From: '.$from_state.' ('.$from_country.') To: '.$to_state.' ('.$to_country.')';
```

As long as each `hash_id` is unique, this will create a new array element for each route.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks for this quick solution. I am a novice in php array so this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @JayMarz Don't forget to accept the answer that fits your issue the most, so that other users can save time and good answers be rewarded.

Comment: @ksjohn yes of course. 6 minutes remaining to check to answer.

Comment: @JayMarz Perfect ! My apologies, I didn't noticed the question was so "young". These array questions get answered pretty fast.

Comment: @JayMarz No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$array => array(pWjY=>'Value',
                YA8N=>'Value',);
```

You can add third value with:

```
$array['somekey'] = 'Value';
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
$route_selection[] = [$route->hash_id => 'From: '.$from_state.' ('.$from_country.') To: '.$to_state.' ('.$to_country.')'];
```

to

```
$route_selection[$route->hash_id] =  'From: '.$from_state.' ('.$from_country.') To: '.$to_state.' ('.$to_country.')';
```

Comment: This wont result in the output that he wants, he will get nested arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$route_selection;
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    $from_state = $route->fromState->name;
    $to_state = $route->toState->name;
    $from_country = $route->fromCountry->name;
    $to_country = $route->tocountry->name; 
    $route_selection[$route->hash_id] =  'From: '.$from_state.' ('.$from_country.') To: '.$to_state.' ('.$to_country.')' ;
}
```